# How to draw 2D quantile-based densities of a scatterplot for the outcome variable in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, density-plot, ggridges

I realize this question has been asked in similar ways multiple times here. I am not asking for a scatterplot which includes a density heatmap of the data, as this captures the density of *both* variables as a smooth function. What I am looking for is something like this, which takes a "slice" of the distribution of the outcome variable and overlays it on the scatterplot:

[image]

The best I could come up with something like this:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Get IQR ####
q <- quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, 
              probs = c(.25,.5,.75))
q

#### Label Quantile Regions ####
qiris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(qs = ifelse(Sepal.Length >= q[3],
                     "Q75",
                     ifelse(Sepal.Length >= q[2],
                            "Q50","Q25")))

#### Plot Density and Scatter ####
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Width,
                 y=Sepal.Length),
             data=iris)+
  geom_density(aes(y=Sepal.Length,
                   fill=qs),
               data=qiris)
```

But predictably this fails because it doesn't place the "slice" of the distribution in relation to the predictor values.

[image]

I then came up with a slightly better solution that locates the distribution of values correctly:

```
library(ggridges)

ggplot(qiris, 
       aes(x = Sepal.Length,
           y = qs)) + 
  stat_density_ridges(quantiles = c(0.25,0.5,0.75),
                      geom="density_ridges_gradient",
                      jittered_points = TRUE,
                      position = "raincloud", 
                      alpha = 0.6, 
                      scale = 0.6)+
  coord_flip()
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

However there are still three issues here. First, I can't fit a regression line through it. Second, I would prefer the data points to be next to each other like a normal scatter plot rather than separated spatially by quantile so they're too far away. Third, this isn't including the other variable at all, which is important.

##### Edit

The answer by Allen looks good at first, but I think there is something I'm not seeing in his code. To try to figure this out, I tried using another dataset and saving the inputs as objects in R to make it easier to swap everything. When I do this, I get flat lines across the plot.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Save Objects ####
dfy <- mtcars$mpg # y var
dfx <- mtcars$hp # x var
data <- mtcars # dataset

#### QDATA ####
qdata <- data %>% 
  mutate(cut_group = cut(dfy, 
                         quantile(dfy, c(0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875)),
                         labels = c('Q25', 'Q50', 'Q75')),
         baseline = quantile(dfy, 
                             c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75))[as.numeric(cut_group)]) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(cut_group) %>%
  reframe(dfxx = density(dfx)$x,
          dfy = first(baseline) - density(dfx, bw = 0.5)$y/3) %>%
  rename(dfx = dfxx) 

ggplot(data,
       aes(dfy,
           dfx)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', 
              color = 'gray',
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(color = 'navy',
             shape = 21,
             fill = NA) +
  geom_path(data = qdata,
            aes(group = cut_group), 
            color = 'darkgreen',
            linewidth = 1.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, 
                                    linewidth = 1))
```

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do this by precalculating density of the quantiles and drawing them on as `geom_path`:

```r
quartiles <- quantile(iris$Sepal.Width)
midpoints <- quartiles[-5] + 0.5 * diff(quartiles)

qiris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Q = cut(Sepal.Width, quartiles, labels = paste0('Q', 1:4)),
         baseline = midpoints[as.numeric(Q)]) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(Q) %>%
  reframe(SepalLength = density(Sepal.Length)$x,
          Sepal.Width = first(baseline) - density(Sepal.Length, bw = 0.5)$y/3) %>%
  rename(Sepal.Length = SepalLength) 

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  annotate('rect', xmin = quartiles[-5], xmax = quartiles[-1], ymin = -Inf,
           ymax = Inf, fill = c('gray', NA, 'gray', NA), alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate('text', x = midpoints, y = 9, label = paste0('Q', 1:4)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = 'gray', se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(color = 'navy', shape = 21, fill = NA) +
  geom_path(data = qiris, aes(group = Q), color = 'darkgreen',
            linewidth = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, linewidth = 1))
```

[image]

For the `mtcars` example, you will need to select a different bandwidth and multiplier for the density to get it into approximately the same scale as the existing variables:

```r
quartiles <- quantile(mtcars$mpg)
midpoints <- quartiles[-5] + 0.5 * diff(quartiles)

qmtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Q = cut(mpg, quartiles, labels = paste0('Q', 1:4)),
         baseline = midpoints[as.numeric(Q)]) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(Q) %>%
  reframe(HP = density(hp)$x,
          mpg = first(baseline) - density(hp, bw = 100)$y * 500) %>%
  rename(hp = HP) 

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  annotate('rect', xmin = quartiles[-5], xmax = quartiles[-1], ymin = -Inf,
           ymax = Inf, fill = c('gray', NA, 'gray', NA), alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate('text', x = midpoints, y = 450, label = paste0('Q', 1:4)) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', color = 'gray', se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(color = 'navy', shape = 21, fill = NA) +
  geom_path(data = qmtcars, aes(group = Q), color = 'darkgreen',
            linewidth = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, linewidth = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 That looks like what I need. The only thing I'm confused by is the first mutate function. Why are there four quantiles in one part and three in the other parts? I also think it looks backwards cuz I made Sepal Length the DV. Not sure if that affects interpretation here.

Comment: Hmm something is off or I'm just not seeing what it is. I have edited my question for clarification.

Comment: The problem with quantiles is that they represent a single point on the x axis, whereas to create density curves we need a range of points. If you want the ranges centered on Q25, Q50 and Q75 then you need to take a range of points around each. There are four quantiles acting as the bookends for the ranges of which each of the three quantiles is the central value. It might be better to do this using each of four quartiles. I see what you mean about the DV, but this is an arbitrary example and that shouldn't matter. I'll switch it round, and also show how to fix your second example.

Comment: Thanks that would be helpful. I also realize now that the `mtcars$hp` data probably isn't the most informative way of doing this given it's discrete and doesn't contain many observations.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand that doesn't matter too much - see my update for how to handle the mtcars example